# create visual Binary Search Tree with only these public methods

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to print a visual representation of a binary search tree, but I can only access these specified methods. I just need some pseudo code. I can't seem to think of a way without accessing the root node, which i cannot. The BST is in java. It needs to grow and shrink accordingly.

I think my first step is to order the keys in levels (level 0 being root, level 1 being children of root and so on)

Here are the methods:

```
size()

height()

isEmpty()

contains(Key key)

get(Key key)

put(Key key, Value val)

min()

max()

floor(Key key)

select(int k)

rank(Key key) <--returns an int value

keys() <--returns iterable<key> from lowest key to highest(Queue filled with integer values)

levelOrderTraversal() <--returns iterable<key>(Queue filled with integer values)

inOrderTraversal() <--returns iterable<key>(Queue filled with integer values)

preOrderTraversal() <--returns iterable<key>(Queue filled with integer values)

postOrderTraversal() <--returns iterable<key>(Queue filled with integer values)
```

The keys are integer values not exceeding 100, in other words, 2 digit values(ex 8 represented as 08)

sample expected output:

```
      5
    /   \
   /     \
  3       9
 / \     / \
1   4   8   10
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What does the `rank` method return? What order does the `keys` method return the keys in? Also the first element in the preOrderTraversal will give you the `root`. Given any two traversals, you can construct the entire tree. Given the root, you can also print the tree.
What is it that you aren't clear with?

Comment: The first thing you get from `preOrderTraversal` should be the root.

Comment: Sorry for my absence of clarity. The traversal methods return an iterable queue that is enqueued with keys. The keys in the tree are Integer values, not nodes. The rank method returns int values. The keys() method returns the keys in low to high(ex. 1,2,3,4,6,10) order. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem I'm having, but don't I need the root Node, not the root key(an integer)?